# UITableView: How to revert a user input

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UITableView with a couple items and I've added a cell that says "No More Items" to the bottom of the UITableView list. I'm preventing the "NMI" cell from being re-ordered, but I can still take one of the other items and drag it underneath the "NMI" cell.

When my view tells me: tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath, I don't modify the model and reorder the array of items. However, even if I don't modify the model, the UITableView still reflects the new order.

What I'm looking for is a method to reject the UITableView's change. So when tableView says "hey the user is moving this row to the end of the list, you should update the model," the controller can respond and say "wait, that row can't be moved to the end of the list. don't do that"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this delegate method to check if reordering is allowed or not.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldReorderColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex toColumn:(NSInteger)newColumnIndex
```

Comment: Lol, this is much more elegant than what I was doing before. Thanks!